# javascript 'over-clicking' bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bug in Javascript where I am animating the margin left property of a parent container to show its child divs in a sort of next/previous fashion. Problem is if clicking 'next' at a high frequency the if statement seems to be ignored (i.e. only works if click, wait for animation, then click again) :

```
 if (marLeft === (-combinedWidth + (regWidth) + "px")) {

                           //roll margin back to 0

                        }
```

An example can be seen on jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ZQg5V/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you click fast, the animation gets queued (waiting since browser is busy responding to click events)

Comment: Can you specify a browser?  It works fine on Chrome.

Comment: Seems to be all browsers, Including Chrome (build 11) - tested on IE7-9 , Firefox and Chrome

Comment: - I should have explained after the black scroll, it should slide back to green rather than continue on white :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes is better if you create a function to take care of the animation, instead of writting animation code on every event handler (next, back). Also, users won't have to wait for the animation to finish in order to go the nth page/box.

Maybe this will help you:

```
if (jQuery) {
    var $next = $(".next"),
        $back = $(".back"),
        $box = $(".box"),
        regWidth = $box.width(),
        $contain = $(".wrap")
        len = $box.length;

    var combinedWidth = regWidth*len;

    $contain.width(combinedWidth);



    var currentBox = 0; // Keeps track of current box

    var goTo = function(n) {
        $contain.animate({
            marginLeft: -n*regWidth
        }, {
            queue: false, // We don't want animations to queue
            duration: 600
        });

        if (n == 0) $back.fadeOut('fast');
        else $back.fadeIn('fast');

        currentBox = n;
    };




    $next.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var go = currentBox + 1;
        if (go >= len) go = 0; // Index based, instead of margin based...
        goTo(go);
    });




    $back.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var go = currentBox - 1;
        if (go <= 0) go = 0; //In case back is pressed while fading...
        goTo(go);
    });

}
```

Here's an updated version of your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/victmo/ZQg5V/5/

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @victmo - that's a nice succinct way to achieve the desired bug free effect - mucho gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code which will basically check if the container is being animated just return from the function.

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQg5V/4/)

```
                 $next.click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    if($contain.is(":animated")){
                        return;
                    }

                    var marLeft = $contain.css('margin-left'),
                        $this = $(this);

                    if (marLeft === (-combinedWidth + (regWidth) + "px")) {
                        $contain.animate({
                            marginLeft: 0
                        }, function () {
                            $back.fadeOut('fast');
                        });
                    } else {
                        $back.fadeIn(function () {
                            $contain.animate({
                                marginLeft: "-=" + regWidth + "px"
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    if (marLeft > -combinedWidth) {
                        $contain.animate({
                            marginLeft: 0
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to track if the animation is taking place.  Pseudocode:

```
var animating = false;

function myAnimation() {
  if (animating) return;
  animating = true;     

  $(this).animate({what:'ever'}, function() {
    animating = false;
  });
}
```

Crude, but it should give you the idea.

Edit: Your current code works fine for me as well, even if I jam out on the button.  On firefox.